# How to order Firebase IDs chronologically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm wondering if there's a simple method in Javascript to arrange two Firebase user IDs chronologically from when they were created? As I understand it, the first half of a Firebase ID is made up of a mixture of letters and numbers (which represent the time at which the ID was created), and the second half is a randomised string of letters and numbers (which should ensure that even two IDs that are created at the same millisecond will be different).

I'm wondering, if you have two Firebase IDs, for example:
`qofV6w2odvZEBnPaE828awAx9rc2` and `FK2n0xyLRKwQGrysfwBxQdP35Kw7`
is there a way to order them using Javascript so that the one that was created by Firebase first will be first, and the one created more recently will be second?

I'm not sure if this is possible in Javascript without some Firebase code (if Firebase use their own algorithm to create the IDs), but I'm wondering is it possible to order the IDs using only Javascript? And if not, what's the best method to go about this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing two concepts here:

- Firebase Authentication User IDs (also known as UIDs), which are just a sequence of random characters that identify a user.
- Firebase Database push IDs (created by calling `push()` or `childByAutoId()`), which are auto-generate, continuously increasing keys.

The push IDs of the database are inherently ordered. By UIDs from authentication are not.

If you want to have a list of Firebase Authentication users in the order in which they were created, you should store the user information in the database. While you could store them under a push ID to get them chronologically, it is more idiomatic to store the users under their UID. If you'd add a timestamp to each user though, you could still get them listed in creation order.

Samples JSON:

```
Users
  uidOfEmily:
      creationTimestamp: 1484320868847
      name: "Emily"
  uidOfPuf:
      creationTimestamp: 1452784908658
      name: "Frank"
```

Code to order by creation time:

```
ref.child("Users").orderBy("creationTimestamp").on("child_added"...
```

Comment: Ah this is perfect, thanks again for your help Frank!